# AJAX runs onload and at set intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to get my AJAX to work when the document loads and runs every 20 seconds. How do i go about doing this? I have got it to work for every 20 seconds but cant get it to work when the document loads. Any help would be brilliant.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.setInterval(function(){

var jobid = $('#jobid').text();
var filename = $('#filename').text();


    $.ajax({
        url: "../progress_bar.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: {"value1": jobid, "value2": filename},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responce){
                $("#progress").html(responce);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call 

    }, 20000);

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: So make a function and call it.... and set interval to it....

Answer (score 2):

For ajax requests one should always use recursive timeouts instead of intervals ( cause the request may last longer then the interval, so there are multiple requests done at a time ) , which also solves the main problem:

```
//may wrap the whole thing into an onload listener
(function update(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "../progress_bar.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: {"value1": jobid, "value2": filename},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responce){
            $("#progress").html(responce);
            //update again in 20secs:
            setTimeout(update, 20000);
        } 
    });  

})(); //start immeadiately
```

A small demo:

```js
console.log("load");
(function next(){
  console.log("run");
  setTimeout( next, 1000);
})()
```